# How to run expo ejected app on android studio

Tags: react-native, expo

My App crashes at launch

```
ejected expoKit 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gy.expoproject/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL host: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL host: ""
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1405)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:916)
        at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:165)
        at host.exp.exponent.kernel.ExponentUrls.addExponentHeadersToUrl(ExponentUrls.java:45)
        at host.exp.exponent.kernel.ExponentUrls.addExponentHeadersToManifestUrl(ExponentUrls.java:57)
        at host.exp.exponent.ExponentManifest.fetchManifest(ExponentManifest.java:220)
        at host.exp.exponent.ExponentManifest.fetchManifest(ExponentManifest.java:204)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.fetchRemoteManifest(AppLoader.java:186)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.startTimerAndFetchRemoteManifest(AppLoader.java:182)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.startTimerAndFetchRemoteManifest(AppLoader.java:176)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.access$800(AppLoader.java:20)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader$3.onError(AppLoader.java:153)
        at host.exp.exponent.ExponentManifest.fetchCachedManifest(ExponentManifest.java:274)
        at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.start(AppLoader.java:91)
        at host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity.onCreate(ExperienceActivity.java:241)
        at host.exp.exponent.experience.DetachActivity.onCreate(DetachActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0):

first run `expo start`, you will get a line like this:

> Your native app is running at expa0d ................. a: //192.1 .... .......: 19000

then go to

> android \ app \ src \ main \ java \ host \ exp \ exponent \ MainActivity.java.

you're going to find a function called `developmentUrl` that contains this line:

`return DetachBuildConstants.DEVELOPMENT_URL;`.

finally, replace it with the line you got it
`return "expa0d ................. a: //192.1 ...........: 19000;`.

more information [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5512#issuecomment-554646376).
I hope this will help you